# How to get the individual components after strip tags in an array?

Tags: php, cakephp

So I have a blog post with a $body variable that has the content of the post. This has images and other content in it.

I want to grab the images alone and get an array of the images enclosed in the  tag.

```
$images = strip_tags($body, '<img>');
```

gives me all the images in one variable, how do i convert this into an array of images?

I am looking for an output array like,

```
[0] => <img.../>
[1] => <img.../>
```

Comment: Why don't try php DOM parser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use preg_match_all to accomplish what you want.

```
$count = preg_match_all('/<img[^>]+>/i', $body, $images);

for ($i = 0; $i < $count; ++$i) {
    $img = $images[0][$i]; // this is the whole img tag i.e. <img src="blah.jpg" style="..." />
}
```

If necessary, you could then examine each $img for a src to get the url of the image.